# Migrate from the legacy 2 app model (free app + paid "unlocker" app) to in-app payment / billing library?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have 2 apps - users typically install free MAIN app, and if they want, they can purchase paid UNLOCKER app, which is nothing but a dummy apk serving as a license.

In my MAIN app I am simply doing this check:

```
if (packageManager.checkSignatures (
    mainPackage, unlockerPackage == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH {
// ... unlock app
}
```

It's the same business model as KWGT widget - this is [main app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kustom.widget) and this is [unlocker app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kustom.widget.pro)

Now, is there an easy way how to migrate to IAP payment and get rid of dummy UNLOCKER app? Problem is I don't know how to distinguish between:

- "new" users who never purchased my app (these should be asked to pay with IAP)
- "old" users who had already purchased the app, but switched their devices (these should asked to install UNLOCKER again as I'm doing now, or grant them some "dummy" zero IAP purchase)

*1. Is there a way how to programmatically check ur using some billing library call, if a user ever paid for my UNLOCKER app from within MAIN app?*

PS: I have already 10 000+ legacy purchases in the past 5 years, so it's not feasible to send each and every one a PROMO code or support them by mail. It would be way too complicated + I am afraid of receiving bad ratings.